# Neo4j: Deleting nodes increased store file size

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j 3.5.12

I ran a delete of 9.5M nodes.

Before the delete, the total size of all files in the `/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db` folder was 9.1Gb.

After the delete they are 16Gb (i.e. bigger).

I understand [this article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-database-growth/?_gl=1*1yalts*_ga*MTMwNjM1OTAxMC4xNTg5NTI5MTU4*_ga_DL38Q8KGQC*MTYwNzc1OTI2MC40My4xLjE2MDc3NjAyMTcuMA..&_ga=2.148433204.2069798556.1607685753-1306359010.1589529158), but my aim is to reduce the memory that the database uses and according to [these calculations](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/)  the `dbms.memory.pagecache.size` should be the sum of the sizes of the $NEO4J_HOME/data/graph.db/neostore.*.db files and adding e.g. 20% for growth.  My neostore *.db files are now 6.4Gb (I didn't calculate them before the delete annoyingly, so I am unsure if this reduced).

Am I correct in thinking that even though the total size of all files in `/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db` has got bigger, the RAM required will have got smaller as the neostore *.db files within those will have got smaller?

Also, I note that the `dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy` setting for my database is 1 day.  I assume this means that after one day any `neostore.transaction.db` files created by the delete operations would be removed and the total size of all files in the `/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db` would therefore go back down again.  Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, so two days later and checking the file sizes the large transaction log files have been removed, so the second part of this question is answered.  Total size of files in `/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db` is now 8.6Gb.  I would still welcome feedback on the first of my questions though.  "Am I correct in thinking that even though the total size of all files in /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db has got bigger, the RAM required will have got smaller as the neostore *.db files within those will have got smaller?"  i.e. For the RAM calculation, is it ONLY the files ending in .db?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the transaction log files. Look at the *Logging configuration* section of the `neo4j.conf` file and limit the size of logs. Look at the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/logging/#transaction-logging) for more information.